# How do I use environment variables in AWS CLI in Azure devops?

Tags: azure-devops, aws-cli

I'm trying to configure a release in Azure DevOps and I've added AWS CLI since I want to publish to AWS. I have installed AWS from the market place and I have added an AWS CLI task. Inside of the field "Options and paramers" I have written

```
--template-file $(Build:ArtifactStagingDirectory)/build/aws-stack-definition.yml
```

but `$(Build:ArtifactStagingDirectory)` refuses to resolve. What is the correct way to write environment variables inside of the AWS CLI?

The complete error is

> Invalid template path
>   $(Build:ArtifactStagingDirectory)/build/aws-stack-definition.yml

Comment: Try `$(Build.Arfiact...)` and not with `:`

Comment: Turns out the variable doesn't exist, and yes, . should be used instead of : :)

Comment: Great! I added also as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You did it in the correct way, but your mistake is in the variable name.

The correct name is: `Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory` and not with `:`.